# ImageView.setPivot property not responding to data

Tags: java, android, view, imageview

I am having an issue when rotating an image in the screen, is always rotating over the same pivot point which I understand is the (0,0), this is how I am trying to achieve it:

```
private Evidence setVehiclePosition (String sCombination, PointF startPoint, 
PointF endPoint, int position, final Evidence myEvidence) {
    myEvidence.geteImage().setOnTouchListener(this);

    imgViewSelected.setPivotX(imgViewSelected.getWidth());
    imgViewSelected.setPivotY(imgViewSelected.getHeight());
    double angle = MyTrigonometry.angleTwoVectors(startPoint, endPoint);
    PointF imageLocation = null;

    switch (sCombination){

        case "C1":
            //angle += 180;
            break;
        case "C2":
            angle += 90;
            break;
        case "C3":
            break;
        case "C4":
            //angle += 270;
            break;
    }

    imgViewSelected.setRotation((int) angle);
    imageLocation = 
MyConvert.MtsToPixs(MyTrigonometry.getCornerrPoint(startPoint, endPoint, 
MyConvert.PixsToMts(myEvidence.geteImage().getHeight())));

   imgViewSelected.setTranslationX((imageLocation.x + 
MyConvert.getOffset().x));                                                                    
   imgViewSelected.setTranslationY(MyConvert.getScreenResolution().y - ((imageLocation.y) + MyConvert.getOffset().y));
}
```

Regardless of what i put inside the setPivot(anything) it just keep pivoting over the same point, Any hints in this matter?

[image]

DESIRED RESULT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default the pivot point of a view is the center, i.e. `(width/2, height/2)`.
Moreover it's not the image that you are rotating but the view, meaning that if your image is not fully scaled in the view you will have strange behaviours.

To achieve what you are trying to do you need to set the pivot point at coordinates `(0, height)` and rotate the view by passing an angle in **degrees** to the `setRotation` method. And try using temporarly `scaleType=fitXY` to see what really happens to the image in the view when rotated.

Hope it helps !